# Prevent user from entering input that matches previous value

Tags: python

Once the user enters the value for choice1 how can he not enter the same value of it in choice2:

```
choice1=input("Your Value is: \n"+str(value1)+ "\nYou would like to make it your Intelligence,Attack Or Defence level? ")
    if choice1=="Intelligence"or choice1=="intelligence":

        confirm1=input("Your Intelligence value is: "+str(value1)+" Confirm?: ")
        if confirm1=="y"or confirm1=="yes"or confirm1=="Yes":
            Intelligence=value1
        elif confirm1=="n"or confirm1=="No"or confirm1=="no":
            UserSecondChoice=input("Then in Which Quality would you like to put it?: ")
            if UserSecondChoice=="Attack"or UserSecondChoice=="attack":
                Attack=value1
                print("Your Attack Is: "+str(value1))
            elif UserSecondChoice=="Defence" or UserSecondChoice=="defence":
                Defence=value1
                print("Your Defence Value is: "+str(value1))
    elif choice1=="Defence"or choice1=="defence":

        confirm2=input("Your Defence value is: "+str(value1)+" Confirm?: ")
        if confirm2=="y"or confirm2=="yes"or confirm2=="Yes":
            Defence=value1
        elif confirm2=="n"or confirm2=="No"or confirm2=="no":
            UserSecondChoice2=input("Then in Which Quality would you like to put it?: ")
            if UserSecondChoice2=="Attack"or UserSecondChoice2=="attack":
                Attack=value1
                print("Your Attack Is: "+str(value1))
            elif UserSecondChoice2=="Intelligence" or UserSecondChoice2=="Intelligence":
                Intelligence=value1
                print("Your Intelligence Value is: "+str(value1))
    elif choice1 == "Attack" or choice1 == "attack":

        confirm3 = input("Your attack value is: " + str(value1) + " Confirm?: ")
        if confirm3 == "y" or confirm3 == "yes" or confirm3 == "Yes":
            Attack = value1
        elif confirm3 == "n" or confirm3 == "No" or confirm3 == "no":
            UserSecondChoice3 = input("Then in Which Quality would you like to put it?: ")
            if UserSecondChoice3 == "defence" or UserSecondChoice3 == "Defence":
                Attack = value1
                print("Your Defence Is: " + str(value1))
            elif UserSecondChoice3 == "Intelligence" or UserSecondChoice3 == "Intelligence":
                Intelligence = value1
                print("Your Intelligence is: " + str(value1))

    value2=random.randint(1,100)
    choice2=input("Your Second Value is: "+str(value2)+" Where Would You Like to Put It: " )
    if choice2=="Intelligence"or choice2=="intelligence":

        confirm4=input("Your Intelligence value is: "+str(value2)+" Confirm?: ")
        if confirm4=="y"or confirm4=="yes"or confirm4=="Yes":
            Intelligence=value2
        elif confirm4=="n"or confirm4=="No"or confirm4=="no":
            UserSecondChoice4=input("Then in Which Quality would you like to put it?: ")
            if UserSecondChoice4=="Attack"or UserSecondChoice4=="attack":
                Attack=value2
                print("Your Attack Is: "+str(value2))
            elif UserSecondChoice4=="Defence" or UserSecondChoice4=="defence":
                Defence=value2
                print("Your Defence Value is: "+str(value2))
    elif choice2=="Defence"or choice2=="defence":

        confirm5=input("Your Defence value is: "+str(value2)+" Confirm?: ")
        if confirm5=="y"or confirm5=="yes"or confirm5=="Yes":
            Defence=value2
        elif confirm5=="n"or confirm5=="No"or confirm5=="no":
            UserSecondChoice5=input("Then in Which Quality would you like to put it?: ")
            if UserSecondChoice5=="Attack"or UserSecondChoice5=="attack":
                Attack=value2
                print("Your Attack Is: "+str(value2))
            elif UserSecondChoice5=="Intelligence" or UserSecondChoice5=="Intelligence":
                Intelligence=value2
                print("Your Intelligence Value is: "+str(value2))
    elif choice2=="Attack"or choice2=="attack":

        confirm6=input("Your Attack value is: "+str(value2)+" Confirm?: ")
        if confirm6=="y"or confirm6=="yes"or confirm6=="Yes":
            Attack=value2
        elif confirm6=="n"or confirm6=="No"or confirm6=="no":
            UserSecondChoice6=input("Then in Which Quality would you like to put it?: ")
            if UserSecondChoice6=="Defence"or UserSecondChoice6=="defence":
                Defence=value2
                print("Your Defence Is: "+str(value2))
            elif UserSecondChoice6=="Intelligence" or UserSecondChoice6=="Intelligence":
                Intelligence=value2
                print("Your Intelligence Value is: "+str(value2))
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] of your problem

Comment: You might want to learn about the `.lower()` and `startswith()` functions

Comment: Go through the **input()** file or functionality, and grab the code, modify according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest breaking your code into functions. Here's a simple loop that prevents your second input from matching the given input

```
def get_choice2(choice1):
    choice2 = input("2: ")
    while choice2 == choice1:
        choice2 = input("2: ")
    return choice2
```